# views.html.index available in which version of playframework

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

We are using the Play 2.10 framework, but `views.html.index` and `views.html.main` are not found in the Play 2.10 lib. Where we can find those?

Comment: This is the basics of Play and any other MVC framework. You do not understand this but still using PLay 2.1? Start reading: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/JavaTemplates

Answer (score 2):

That are your compiled views. When you create your templates inside the views folder, Play automatically compiles them using your extension as package name.

**Example** : `views.html.index` refers to `views/index.scala.html`.

Answer (score 1):

These files will not exist unless you create them, or unless you are using a project template (or sample) that provides them for you - they're not really part of Play itself, but just examples of templates you can write.

As the previous answer says, you can create .scala.html files in the views directory inside your project root directory, and Play will compile them for you.